# post form to database without leaving the page in a php echoed form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I think I really dug myself a hole here. I have a php file that creates a "notification list" with checkboxes. I want it to work in a way so the user will check the notification he read (in order to clean up his/her list), then the form will submit- by checking, and the 'notification' table in the database will be updated. My problem: it works, but it submits to the notification.php file. I don't want that. 
I read several ways to solve it with AJAX but they require the checkboxes id's and as you can see below, The id's are being created by the php...

```
    echo "<form name='noteform' id='noteform' action='notifications.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['type'] == 'group_request') {
            echo "<li><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='" . $row['id'] . "' onclick='document.noteform.submit()' /><p1>" . $row['text'] . " | Approve? </li>";
        }else{
            echo "<li><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='" . $row['id'] . "' /><p1>" . $row['text'] . "</p1></li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</form>";

        $check = isset($_POST['check']) ? $_POST['check'] : array();
            foreach($check as $ch) {
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE notifications SET `read`=1 WHERE id='$ch'");
        }
?>
```

ps. The `if($row['type'] == 'group_request')` is just because that's the only notification type i made so far...

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just plain 'ol javascript?

Comment: for the submitting just JS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* to by any means, but it would make your life a lot easier IMO. Here is a quick solution using jQuery:

```
$('#noteform').on('submit', function(event){
  // Validate or whatever

  // Submit
  $.ajax({
      'type': 'post',
      'data': $(this).serialize(),
      'url': 'path-to-notification.php',
       'timeout': 50000
    }).done(function(response) {
        // success
    }).fail(function(error) {
        // error
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT**
Let's say you have "index.php", and within that file you have your form:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    ....
    <form>
    ....
    </form>
    ....
?>
```

Then either in and external .js file, or within index.php inside of a `<script>` tag, you would have the ajax method(s) above.

Next, you would have `notification.php` that would handle your form action(s).

**notifications.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])
{
    // check the value
    // handle the form element
}

// sanitize the data

// run your update query

// return success/fail to the javascript

?>
```

In a nutshell, that's how I would set things up. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! should I take off the `action=notifications.php method=post` from the form line? Also, where should i put the `UPDATE` command?

Comment: Nope. I would leave those attributes on there. I'll update my suggestion with how you could handle the update.